# disable some Validation according Submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model like belowe:

```
 public class AddPurchaseViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter ...")]
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter ...")]
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter ...")]
    public Guid BusinessPartnerId { get; set;
```

}

and in View I have two Submit button Like this :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="command" value="save">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="command" value="SaveAsTemp" >Save And Temp</button></li>
```

and in controller I have :

```
 public virtual ActionResult Create(AddPurchaseViewModel purchaseViewModel, string command)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(purchaseViewModel);
        var result = AddPurchaseStatus.AddFailed;
        if (command.ToLowerWithTrim()== "Save".ToLowerWithTrim())
            result = _purchaseService.Add(purchaseViewModel);
        else
            result = _purchaseService.AddAsTemp(purchaseViewModel);
        return View();
    }
```

I want when User clicked On Submit button `Save` ,user Should Fill All textboxes in this case ,ModelState handel it and works fine .

but when clicked on `SaveAsTemp` in this case dont Required BusinessPartner to fill .

I dont want Check one by one with If because my model has mor than 20 fields 
.
 Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: **This will help you definetly** [How to put conditional Required Attribute into class property to work with WEB API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642328/how-to-put-conditional-required-attribute-into-class-property-to-work-with-web-a)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the validation on clicking the SaveAsTemp button using JQuery

```
$('input[type="button"][value="SaveAsTemp "]').click(function() {
    var settngs = $.data($('#MyForm'), 'validator').settings;
    settngs.ignore = ".ignore";
});
```

Substitute #MyForm with your form Id

Or for an Individual field

```
$("#SomeValue").removeAttr("data-val-required");
```

Assuming that it its a 'Required' validator

In your controller you can disable/clear errors on specific fileds as follows

```
ModelState["MyField"].Errors.Clear();
```

Comment: I dont want disable all validation , I want just disable one of them .

Comment: Updated answer, are the fields 'required' validation?

Comment: your code just disable in client side and in contoller validatons are enable

Comment: You can disable/clear model errors on specific fields using ModelState["MyField"].Errors.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

Please check conditional validation http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541244/Conditional-ASP-NET-MVC-Validation-using-Data-Anno 
Hope it helped.