# How to make RequiredIf Client-side and server-side validation in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have to make client-side and server-side validation in ASP.NET Core 3.1. I have gone through many blogs but didn't get enough idea in ASP.NET Core MVC.

I have to make a RequiredIf kind of validation. When `BusinessType` is `Business`, the `VATNumber` field is required, but this field is optional if `BusinessType` is `Personal`. Please help.

```
public enum BusinessType
{
    Personal,
    Business
}

public class Profile
{           
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter email")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose business type")]
        [EnumDataType(typeof(BusinessType))]
        public BusinessType BusinessType { get; set; }    

        [Display(Name="VAT Number")]
        public string VATNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: have a look at fluent validation implementation which helps to keep your code clean, and all business validations away from model this helps you to implement better unit testing, https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#getting-started

Comment: @coder_b I can't use fluent validation in the project and so I have to manage on the model.

Comment: well in that case you can create your own validation attributes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642328/how-to-put-conditional-required-attribute-into-class-property-to-work-with-web-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have implemented both client-side and server-side validation to achieve my requirement. Here is the complete code:

**Enum**

```
   public enum BusinessType
    {
        Personal,
        Business
      }
```

**Profile Model**

```
 public class Profile
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter email")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose business type")]
        [EnumDataType(typeof(BusinessType))]
        public BusinessType BusinessType { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("BusinessType", BusinessType.Business, ErrorMessage = "VAT number is required")]
        [Display(Name = "VAT Number")]
        public string VATNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**RequiredIfAttribute class**

```
 public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }


        public RequiredIfAttribute(string propertyName, object value, string errorMessage = "")
        {
            PropertyName = propertyName;
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            Value = value;
        }


        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var instance = validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            var type = instance.GetType();
            var proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
            if (proprtyvalue != null)
            {
                if (proprtyvalue.ToString() == Value.ToString() && value == null)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }


        public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val-vatNumber", ErrorMessage);
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val-vatNumber-businessType", Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**requiredIfBusinessTypeValidate.js**

```
$.validator.addMethod('vatNumber', function (value, element, params) {

    var genre = $(params[0]).val(), businessType = params[1], vat = value;

    var selectedBusinessType = $("#BusinessType option:selected").text();

    if (selectedBusinessType === businessType) {
        if (value.length === 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('vatNumber', ['businessType'], function (options) {
    var element = $(options.form).find('select#BusinessType')[0];

    options.rules['vatNumber'] = [element, options.params['businessType']];
    options.messages['vatNumber'] = options.message;
});
```

**View**

```
<h4>Profile</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Index">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BusinessType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="BusinessType" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<BusinessType>()">
                    <option value="">Choose</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="BusinessType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="VATNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="VATNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="VATNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

 @section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script src="~/js/requiredIfBusinessTypeValidate.js"></script>
 }
```

**Controller**

```
   public class ProfileController : Controller
    {
       
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Profile profile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Write business logic here ...
            }
            return View(profile);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Intead of using hardcoded names we can make it dynamic based on the anotation values.
Here is the server side

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides conditional validation based on related property value.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class RequiredIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the other property name that will be used during validation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The other property name.
    /// </value>
    public string OtherProperty { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the display name of the other property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The display name of the other property.
    /// </value>
    public string OtherPropertyDisplayName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the other property value that will be relevant for validation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The other property value.
    /// </value>
    public object OtherPropertyValue { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether other property's value should match or differ from provided other property's value (default is <c>false</c>).
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> if other property's value validation should be inverted; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    /// <remarks>
    /// How this works
    /// - true: validated property is required when other property doesn't equal provided value
    /// - false: validated property is required when other property matches provided value
    /// </remarks>
    public bool IsInverted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value that indicates whether the attribute requires validation context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the attribute requires validation context; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    public override bool RequiresValidationContext
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RequiredIfAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="otherProperty">The other property.</param>
    /// <param name="otherPropertyValue">The other property value.</param>
    public RequiredIfAttribute(string otherProperty, object otherPropertyValue)
        : base()
    {
        this.OtherProperty = otherProperty;
        this.OtherPropertyValue = otherPropertyValue;
        this.IsInverted = false;
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies formatting to an error message, based on the data field where the error occurred.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name to include in the formatted message.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An instance of the formatted error message.
    /// </returns>
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            base.ErrorMessageString,
            name,
            this.OtherPropertyDisplayName ?? this.OtherProperty,
            this.OtherPropertyValue,
            this.IsInverted ? "other than " : "of ");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the specified value with respect to the current validation attribute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to validate.</param>
    /// <param name="validationContext">The context information about the validation operation.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An instance of the <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult" /> class.
    /// </returns>
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (validationContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("validationContext");
        }

        PropertyInfo otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.OtherProperty);
        if (otherProperty == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(
                string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Could not find a property named '{0}'.", this.OtherProperty));
        }

        object otherValue = otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

        // check if this value is actually required and validate it
        if (!this.IsInverted && object.Equals(otherValue, this.OtherPropertyValue) ||
            this.IsInverted && !object.Equals(otherValue, this.OtherPropertyValue))
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }

            // additional check for strings so they're not empty
            string val = value as string;
            if (val != null && val.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-required-if", ErrorMessage);
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-required-if-other-name", OtherProperty);
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-required-if-other-value", OtherPropertyValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

And here is the client side required-if.js

```
    $.validator.addMethod('required-if', function (value, element, params) {
    var targetValue = params['other-value'];
    var otherElement = $("#" + params['other-name']);
    var otherCurrentValue = otherElement.val();
    if (targetValue != otherCurrentValue) {
        return true;
    }
    if (value.length === 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('required-if', ['other-name', 'other-value'], function (options) {
    options.rules['required-if'] = [options.element, options.params];
    options.messages['required-if'] = options.message;
    options.messages['required'] = options.message;
});
```

and here is the usage

```
[RequiredIf("OtherPropertyName", otherPropertyValue: true, AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string RequiredPropertyTest { get; set; }
```

Now when the OtherPropertyName has a value true and RequiredPropertyTest is empty the validation error will popup

Answer (score 0):

You could custom validation like below:

```
public class RequieredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _otherProperty;

    public RequieredIfAttribute(string otherProperty)
    {
        _otherProperty = otherProperty;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string data = (string)value;

        BusinessType selectedType = (BusinessType)validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_otherProperty).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) && selectedType == BusinessType.Business)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("VATNumber is requiered.");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Profile
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose business type")]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(BusinessType))]
    public BusinessType BusinessType { get; set; }

    [RequieredIf("BusinessType")]        //add this...
    [Display(Name = "VAT Number")]
    public string VATNumber { get; set; }
}
```

View(Index.cshtml):

```
@model Profile
<form asp-action="Create">
    <select asp-for="BusinessType" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<BusinessType>()"></select>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="VATNumber" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="VATNumber" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="VATNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Profile profile)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //do your stuff...
        return View("Index");
    }
    //do your stuff...
    return View("Privacy");
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This only does server-side validation. How to extend it to support client-side validation?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Sahib's answer, which is really working well for me, you obviously need to add:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System.Globalization;
```