# .NET JSON Property custom required logic

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-4.8

Suppose the following class Definition

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I now need the property `Text` to be **conditionally required**. E.g. when `Number > 10` then I need `Text` to be present in the json string. If `Number <= 10` it can be omitted. I **cannot** simply use the `Required` Property of the attribute

```
[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
public string Text { get;set; }
```

As this is non conditional. Is there a way I can enforce this? Some examples

```
{ "Number": 5 } // < valid 
{ "Number": 20 } // < invalid
{ "Number": 20, "Text": "Bar" } // < valid
```

Our project is using Newtonsoft Json in .NET Framework v4.8
Our classes are serialized using middleware (i.e. we run an API on IIS). We do not manually call `JsonConvert.Deserizalize<T>(input)` anywhere.

Comment: How about "manually" validating after the deserialization?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put conditional Required Attribute into class property to work with WEB API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642328/how-to-put-conditional-required-attribute-into-class-property-to-work-with-web-a)

Comment: @UweKeim that would indeed be a possibility but I am not a big fan of it. I'd need to manually call that validation method after every instantiation. And even if I could somehow automate that, suppose that in the future I am reading JSON text from disk too. The same check needs to happen there and someone in the team then must remember to add that check there too. This is a code smell

Comment: [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=netframework-4.8) is very extensible and will automatically be respected by many .net frameworks. Validations based on these attributes can be triggered manually as well.

Comment: @pfx I went with that approach yes. Unfortunately I still need to manually call `Validator.TryValidateObject(...)` instead of it being part of the JSON deserialization. In fact it is completely standalone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enforce that `Text` is present and non-null when `Number` is > 10 and require a purely Newtonsoft solution, you could do so in a parameterized constructor:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    // Make public if you want to enforce the same requirements during regular construction
    protected Foo(int number, string text) 
    {
        if (number > 10 && text == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("missing text");
        this.Number = number;
        this.Text = text;
    }
    
    // Remove if you want to enforce the same requirements during regular construction
    public Foo() { }
    
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Do note that the constructor parameters must have the same names as the corresponding properties, ignoring differences in case.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/52kQEG).

Alternatively, if you don't like using a constructor for some reason, you could do the check in an [`[OnDeserialized]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbackAttributes.htm) callback:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserializedMethod(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (Number > 10 && Text == null)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("missing text");
        }
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LWVkSR).

Note that both solutions treat a `null` value for `Text` as equivalent to a missing value.  If you want `{"Number":20, "Text":null}` to be valid you will need to adopt a more complex solution, such as remembering whether `Text` was ever set and checking that in the `[OnDeserialized]` callback:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    string text;
    bool textSpecified;
    public string Text { get => text; set { text = value; textSpecified = true; } }
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserializedMethod(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (Number > 10 && !textSpecified)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("missing text");
        }
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oTn4zP).

Comment: This is a very usefull answer thanks! Regarding the uncertainty between missing the property of having it be `null`, that is fortunately in my real scenario not of importance